# bundle install from a new server errors due to git ssh key

Tags: bash, git, jenkins, ssh, bundler

I am installing a new server via `chef`
and coping ssh private and public keys into it.

After creating it, I am deploying the application onto it via `jenkins` and running `bundle install`, it fails due to

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

If I ssh into the server and run the `bundle install` command myself, I get prompted with

```
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (104.192.143.1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

same for github

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.129)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

I press yes, the bundle finishes. On top of that, if I now run the jenkins job again, the bundle finishes successfully.

Any ideas, how to auto approve this authenticity of those remote servers via jenkins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approved information is held in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, so you can copy that together with your keys, that way you know what keys have been approved.

Alternatively you can retrieve the information using `ssh-keyscan` and append  the result to your server's `known_hosts`, note however that if you do automatically you pose the risk of accepting MITM's machine (since you don't see what has been approved).

Finally you can disable host checking `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no github.com`, but that is equally bad to automating ssh-keyscan.